# How to merge two arrays and concat the values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for an easy solution to create a little function to merge two arrays with value concat (I'm using it to create html tag attribute):

```
$default["class"] = "red";

$new["class"] = "green";
$new["style"] = "display:block"
```

The result:

```
$res["class"] = "red green";
$res["style"] = "display: block";
```

and one more option: 
if the `$new` is not an array, just concat with the `$default["class"]` (if this exist), and the other side: if the `$default` is a simple string, convert to array: `$default["class"] = $default`;

I created a function but would like to use an easier, shorter way for that:

```
function attrMerge( $default, $new="" ){
    $res = array();

    if(!is_array($default)) {
        $res["class"] = $default;
    }
    else {
        $res = $default;
    }

    if( $new !== "" ){
        if(!is_array($new)) {
            if(isset($res["class"])){
                $res["class"].= " ".$new;
            }
        }
        else {
            foreach($new as $key=>$value) {
                if( isset($res[$key]) ) {
                    $res[$key].= " ".$value;
                }
                else {
                    $res[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

$a = attrMerge("red", array("class"=>"green", "style"=>"display: block;"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the function that you need. I have initialised the css classes and styles as empty and in depends what you pass into the function then you get the relevant array

```
/**
* This function returns an array of classes and styles
*
* @param $default
* @param $new
* @return array
*/
function attrMerge($default=null, $new=nul)
{
    $result = array();
    $result['class'] = "";
    $result['style'] = "";

    // add default class if exists
    if (!empty($default) && is_string($default)) {
        // $default is string
        $result['class'] = $default;
    }
    if (!empty($default)
        && is_array($default)
    ) {
        if (array_key_exists('class', $default)
            && !empty($default['class'])
        ) {
           // $default['class'] exists and it's not empty
           $result['class'] = $default['class'];
        }
        if (array_key_exists('style', $default)
            && !empty($default['style'])
        ) {
           // $default['style'] exists and it's not empty
           $result['style'] = $default['style'];
        }
    }

    // add additional classes OR styles
    if (!empty($new)) {
        if(!is_array($new)) {
            $result['class'] = empty($result['class'])
                ? $new
                : $result['class'] . " " . $new;
        } else {
            foreach ($new as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($result[$key])) {
                    $result[$key] = empty($result[$key])
                        ? $value
                        : $result[$key] . " " . $value;
                } else {
                    $result[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your function is working fine with class attribute, but clear `$default["style"]` and left only the `$new["style"]` value.

Comment: I added the correction. I didn't know that you can pass style as $default value like the class

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused at the end:) This function is working great for me. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

A way I believe suits your need, hopefully it's as adaptable and effecient as you were expecting.

```
$array1 = array(
'class' => 'class1',
'style' => 'display: none;'
);

$array2 = array(
    'class' => 'class2'
);

$arrayFinal = arrayMerge($array1, $array2);
var_dump($arrayFinal);

function arrayMerge($arr1, $arr2 = ''){
    // Array of attributes to be concatenated //
    $attrs = array('class');
    if(is_array($arr2)){
        foreach($attrs as $attr){
            if(isset($arr1[$attr]) && isset($arr2[$attr])){
            // Not using .= to allow for smart trim (meaning empty check etc isn't needed //
            $arr1[$attr] = trim($arr1[$attr] . ' ' . $arr2[$attr]);
            }
        }
    }else{
        $arr1['class'] = trim($arr1['class'] . ' ' . $arr2);
    }

    return $arr1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this function is working when arrays are income the function. There is an option: these variables are simple strings instead of arrays. I wouldn't like to put them into array every time.

Comment: There is an if statement that checks if it is an array, otherwise it uses it as a string and adds it to "class". As your function does.

Comment: Also, I added an array ($attrs), so you can choose what is added to what. E.g., display won't be added / concatenated. Only class, because class is in $attrs.

Comment: Please check this:
`$arrayFinal = arrayMerge("class3", $array2);`
What is the output in this case? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$def = ['class' => 'red'];
$new = ['class' => 'green', 'style' => 'style'];

function to_array($in) {
    return is_array($in) ? $in : ['class' => $in];
}

$def = to_array($def);
$new = to_array($new);

$res = $def;
array_walk($new, function ($val, $key) use (&$res) {
   $res[$key] = trim(@$res[$key] . ' ' . $val);
});

var_dump($res);
```